# routes not working ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have write down in routes

```
match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: [:get, :post]
```

when i submit the form show me error

My form code is like this

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: "new"}  do |f| %>
```

And form submit on this url not on singup

```
http://localhost:3000/users/new
```

and show me error

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/new"

Rails.root: /home/jaskaran/rails_project
```

when i check rake output, it's show me

```
jaskaran@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:~/rails_project$ rake routes
        Prefix Verb          URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
          root GET           /                              static_pages#home
          help GET           /help(.:format)                static_pages#help
         about GET           /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
       contact GET           /contact(.:format)             static_pages#contact
    microposts GET           /microposts(.:format)          microposts#index
               POST          /microposts(.:format)          microposts#create
 new_micropost GET           /microposts/new(.:format)      microposts#new
edit_micropost GET           /microposts/:id/edit(.:format) microposts#edit
     micropost GET           /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#show
               PATCH         /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#update
               PUT           /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#update
               DELETE        /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#destroy
         users GET           /users(.:format)               users#index
               POST          /users(.:format)               users#create
      new_user GET           /users/new(.:format)           users#new
     edit_user GET           /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
          user GET           /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
               PATCH         /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
               PUT           /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
               DELETE        /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
        signup POST|GET|POST /signup(.:format)              users#new
     posts_new GET           /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
  posts_create POST          /posts/create(.:format)        posts#create
```

I am learning ruby and rails 4 +

Comment: Post your `rake routes` output.

Comment: Just run `rake routes` in the console and post the output in the question.

Comment: <%= form_for @user, url => url_for(:action => 'signup')   do |f| %> this one

Comment: Run rake routes command in the console man

Comment: You want to match `/signup` and you're calling `/users/new`. Replace `action: "new"` to `action: signup_path` or directly by `signup_path`. I don't remember exactly the syntax.

Comment: Please check it i have write down in query @pavan

Comment: @bobbystouket yes i want this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though your route maps to the new action of the users controller, your form needs to point to the URI pattern, in your case `/signup`.

When in doubt, you can find the URI pattern and other information in your routes. Run `rake routes` in your console and you'll see this:

```
signup GET|POST /signup(.:format)     users#new
```

Rails generates helper methods to use in your views for each of the routes, based on the route prefix. In your case you can use the helper method `signup_path`. To fix the problem, change your view code to this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: signup_path do |f| %>
```

Check the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes) for more information.

Comment: Great Man I want this form 2mro

Comment: every one has -1 my query Why i am learing I am not progrmmer

Comment: It seems your question gets upvoted now. It's a fine question and you provided plenty of detail. Good luck on your Rails journey!

Comment: You're welcome. If you run into other obstacles while learning, don't hesitate to ask another question on Stackoverflow!